# Does this prove the injectivity of f?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $V, W$ are $K$-vector spaces with a linear transformation $F:V\to W$,  then $F$ is an injection if there exists another linear transformation $G$ with $G\circ F=\operatorname{Id}_V$.

Proof:
Take $x,y \in V$ with $F(x) = F(y)$

$F(G(F(x))) = F(G(F(y)))$

$F(G(F(x))) - F(G(F(y))) = 0$

$F(G(F(x)) - G(F(x))) = 0$

$F(G(F(x) - F(y))) = 0$

$F(G(0)) = 0 $

Comment: It's easier than that. If $F(x)=F(y)$ then $G(F(x))=G(F(y))$. Since $G(F(x))=x$ and $G(F(y))=y$ we know that $x=y$ so $F$ is an injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to @John Douma I found an easier solution:

if $F(x) = F(y)$ then $G(F(x)) = G(F(y))$.
which equates to $x=y$ because $G(F(x))=x$ and $G(F(y))=y$ (which should have been way more obvious to me).